# What does it mean an ideal is nilpotent modulo another ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Reference:Chatters, A. W.; Hajarnavis, C. R. (1971), "Non-commutative rings with primary decomposition", Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 22: 73–83, doi:10.1093/qmath/22.1.73

Let $R$ be an rng and $I,J$ be ideals of $R$.

What does it mean that "$I$ is nilpotent modulo $J$"?

Does this mean that $I^n\subset J$ for some $n$?

Or does this mean that $a^n\in J$ for some $n$, for each $a\in I$?

Comment: $I^n\subset J$ for some $n$. The second concept is called a nil ideal.

Comment: @Eoin Thank you :) {}{}{}